# PowerBuilder SQL on SQL Server 2008 - CASE statement with computed column in SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, case, calculated-columns

I am attempting to create computed columns with a CASE statement using [an example from Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx).

I will appreciate any help or pointers!!

The relevant example code is:

```
SELECT   
    ProductNumber, Category =  
      CASE ProductLine  
         WHEN 'R' THEN 'Road'  
         WHEN 'M' THEN 'Mountain'  
         WHEN 'T' THEN 'Touring'  
         WHEN 'S' THEN 'Other sale items'  
         ELSE 'Not for sale'  
    END,  
    Name  
FROM 
    Production.Product  
ORDER BY 
    ProductNumber;  
GO
```

And I 'think' I am doing the same thing below:

```
SELECT 
    Convert ( char(10),"") No,   
    Convert ( char(15),"") vendor,   
    car_type.car_type_desc,
    origin_st = 
        case voucher.pu_is_airport
            when 'F' then Convert( char(50),  rtrim(ltrim(operator_archive.pu_st_no)) + " " + rtrim(ltrim(operator_archive.pu_st_name)) )  
            else Convert( char(50), "")  
            end
        origin = 
        case voucher.pu_is_airport
            when 'F' then Convert( char(50),  rtrim(ltrim(operator_archive.pu_city)) + ", " + rtrim(ltrim(operator_archive.pu_county)))  
            else Convert( char(50),  rtrim(ltrim(operator_archive.pu_county))  
            end
         voucher.confirmation_no,   
         voucher.pu_is_airport,   
         operator_archive.dest_st_name  
FROM 
    voucher,   
    car_type,   
    operator_archive  
WHERE 
    (voucher.car_type = car_type.car_type_id) and  
    (operator_archive.confirmation_no = voucher.confirmation_no) and  
    ((dbo.voucher.pu_date_time >= :start_date) AND  
     (dbo.voucher.pu_date_time <= :end_date) AND  
     (dbo.voucher.account_no = :account) AND  
     (dbo.voucher.status_flag not in ('9','X','C','F')) AND  
    (dbo.voucher.payment_type in ('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8')))
```

but the server tells me that I have an error as:

> SQLSTATE = 37000
>   [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'origin'.

I have tried it with the comma after 'End' and then I get an error stating:

> SQLSTATE = 37000
>   [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'end'.

Comment: oh, man, there's so many issues here. First of all, to use strings you need to use single quotes `Convert( char(50), '')` instead of double quotes `Convert( char(50), "")` (you have to change that everywhere. Also, you absolutely need the comma after `END`, the problem is that, for instance, you are missing a parenthesis here: `Convert( char(50),  rtrim(ltrim(operator_archive.pu_county))`, it should be `Convert( char(50),  rtrim(ltrim(operator_archive.pu_county)))`

Comment: This is my first post here.  My compiler allows single quotes, but you were right about the missing ')'.  I don't see a place to vote for the response, but thank you.  After an hour of trying this and that, I lost track of the punctuation.  PEM.

Comment: THIS IS RESOLVED, BUT NOT SURE HOW TO FLAG IT AS SUCH.  PEM

Comment: You can post an answer explaining what was wrong, how you solved it and then you can accept that answer

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to comments from Lamak, I was able to resolve the issue by adding a missing parenthesis and commas after the 'end' statement.  Thanks Lamak!!